# APA-Biblatex Problem with amount of authors

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, author-number

I've got a problem with the biblatex-apa version.

Here is the relevant part of my header:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
12pt,
headings=normal
bibtotoc,
pointlessnumbers
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,minbibnames=5, maxbibnames=5]{biblatex}  
\bibliography{literatur}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ addabbrvspace al\adddot}}
\newcommand*{\mcite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}

\renewcommand\finalandcomma{\addcomma}

\begin{document}

\mcite{Brodbeck2000}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

with this journal article

```
@article{Brodbeck2000,
author = {Brodbeck, Felix C and Frese, Michael and Akerblom, S and Audia, G and 
Bakacsi, G and Bendova, H and Bodega, D and Bodur, Muzaffer and Booth, S and Brenk, K 
and Castel, P},
journal = {Journal of Occupational and Organizational Psychology},
pages = {1--29},
title = {{Cultural variation of leadership prototypes across 22 European countries}},
volume = {73},
year = {2000}
}
```

The problem is that biblatex has a problem with this amount of authors. Instead of stopping after six authors and putting "et al" after the last one biblatex writes:

Brodbeck, F. C., Frese, M., Akerblom, S., Audia, G., Bakacsi, G., Bendova, H., . . .
Castel, P. (2000). Cultural variation of leadership prototypes across 22 European
countries. Journal of Occupational and Organizational Psychology, 73, 1–29.

Does anybody know how do fix it, so that biblatex only puts 6 authors in the bibliography (apa-style) and then "et al."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redefine the author macro:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{latex6.bib}
 @article{Brodbeck2000,
author = {Brodbeck, Felix C and Frese, Michael and Akerblom, S and Audia, G and 
Bakacsi, G and Bendova, H and Bodega, D and Bodur, Muzaffer and Booth, S and Brenk, K and Castel, P},
journal = {Journal of Occupational and Organizational Psychology},
pages = {1--29},
title = {Cultural variation of leadership prototypes across 22 European countries},
volume = {73},
year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,minbibnames=5, maxbibnames=5]{biblatex}  
\bibliography{latex6}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ \addabbrvspace al\adddot}}
\newcommand*\mcite[1]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}

\renewcommand\maxprtauth{7}

\DeclareNameFormat{apaauthor}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=\maxprtauth \AND\value{listcount}<\value{listtotal}}
    {~et.~al.\addspace\setcounter{listcount}{\thelisttotal}}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth\AND\value{listcount}<\value{listtotal}}
      {}%
      {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{usere}{unkauth}\OR\iffieldequalstr{usere}{unkauthdate}}%
        {\iffirstinits
          {\mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}?}}%
          {\mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}?}}}%
        {\iffirstinits
          {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}%
          {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}}}%
  \ifmorenames{\andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}{}}
\renewcommand\finalandcomma{\addcomma}

\begin{document}
\mcite{Brodbeck2000}
\printbibliography   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is correct APA 6th edition style, see section 7.01, example 2.

Comment: unfortunately i need the "et al." alternative, because my teachers wants it that way ... is it possible to change this ?